# Zookeeper on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, apache-zookeeper

Trying to run Zookeeper on OpenShift.

This is not so straightforward due to Zookeeper's hard-coded and static configuration requirements.

Can anyone suggest some recommendation or web resources that discuss ways to overcome these issues.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I tried this a while back on 3.4 https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-zookeeper-cart - the gap was that the internal zookeeper leader port needs to be the same as the external port, and that's hard in V2.  In V3 that's easier - here's the V3 example (although it won't help you on V2) https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/zookeeper