# Using Zookeeper on Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to use [the zookeeper](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/zookeeper/templates/config-script.yaml#L67) helm chart on Openshift and having trouble. Zookeeper tries to write to /conf directory in the above stated helm chart which would fail.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662466/zookeeper-on-openshift) was an answer to my question. But the 2nd link that points to the zookeeper example is broken. [This](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/) does have examples of deploying apps on openshift but none of those are helm charts.

It would be great if anyone can explain how to make the Zookeeper helm chart work on Openshift. TIA.

Comment: There a fork of the repository of the broken link. Check it [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8/tree/master/vendor/github.com/openshift/origin/examples/zookeeper) and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am looking for a way to conusme the same helm charts with minimum modifications since I am using the same helm charts for kubernetes.

Comment: There is a know issue related to it. Please, check [it](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1515943).